# How to use dependency inject for TelemetryConfiguration in Azure Function

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I try to use Dependency injection in Azure Functions for TelemetryConfiguration. In my function I will have it resolved when I inject TelemetryConfiguration in the functions constructor. I suppose I don't really understand how I will do with TelemetryConfiguration in StartUp, thats why I get an exception. How will I add the TelemetryConfiguration I already configured.

I have did an easy example here what I'm doing so far.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
{
    private string OmsModule { get; } = "OMS.VA";

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(
            (o) =>
            {
                o.InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
                o.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
            });
    }
}

public class StopPlaceUpdateTimerTrigger
{
    private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
    private string _azureWebJobsStorage;

    public StopPlaceUpdateTimerTrigger(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
    {
        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }

    [FunctionName("StopPlaceLoader")]
    public async Task StopPlaceLoaderMain([TimerTrigger("%CRON_EXPRESSION%", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimerInfo, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        SetConfig(context);
        var cloudTable = await GetCloudTableAsync();
        if (cloudTable == null)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
        //Do nothing
    }

    private async Task<CloudTable> GetCloudTableAsync()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_azureWebJobsStorage);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(nameof(StopPlaceLoaderCacheRecord));

        if (!await table.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
        return table;
    }

    private void SetConfig(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        _azureWebJobsStorage = config["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
    }
}


//local.settings.json
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol...",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
"EnableMSDeployAppOffline": "True",
    "CRON_EXPRESSION": "0 */5 22-3 * * *",
"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "..."
  }
}
```

I get the following Exception;
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'OMS.VA.RealTime.StopPlaceLoader.StopPlaceUpdateTimerTrigger'.

Comment: how do you do this with azure functions?

Comment: Don't understand your question:-) I'm doing this in Azure functions, the code above with corrections of @IvanYang below. Be more specific in your question and I try to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update:

We can change this line of code `var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;` to `var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();` , since `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is deprecated.

---

Please use the code below for TelemetryConfiguration DI, I test it with a blob trigger function and works well:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp17.MyStartup))]
namespace FunctionApp17
{

    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var configDescriptor = builder.Services.SingleOrDefault(tc => tc.ServiceType == typeof(TelemetryConfiguration));
            if (configDescriptor?.ImplementationFactory != null)
            {
                var implFactory = configDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;
                builder.Services.Remove(configDescriptor);
                builder.Services.AddSingleton(provider =>
                {
                    if (implFactory.Invoke(provider) is TelemetryConfiguration config)
                    {
                        var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
                        newConfig.ApplicationIdProvider = config.ApplicationIdProvider;
                        newConfig.InstrumentationKey = config.InstrumentationKey;

                        return newConfig;
                    }
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public class Function1
    {
        private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public Function1(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
        {
            _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"!!!!!!!!!! C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("this is a test message from DI of telemetry client !!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

the test result as below, I can see the logs in the application insights in azure portal:

[image]

And one more thing, I see you try to use ITelemetry Initializer in your code. You can follow this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3741) for your `ITelemetry Initializer` or `Itelemetry Processor`

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks! In my implementation I changed 
var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
to
var newConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
because TelemetryConfiguration.Active is deprecated from ApplicationInsights SDK 2.11-beta1

Comment: @RogerUhlin, thanks for your sharing, I will update it in my post :)

Answer (score 12):

If you use `builder.Services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>()` to configure, you are using [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

To access the option, you need to do as following:

```
public StopPlaceUpdateTimerTrigger(IOptionsMonitor<TelemetryConfiguration> telemetryConfiguration)
{
    _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration.CurrentValue);
}
```

---

If you just want to directly use TelemetryConfiguration object, you need to add it in service collection:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TelemetryConfiguration >(sp =>
{
    var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
    telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
    telemetryConfiguration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
    return telemetryConfiguration;
}
```

Then you can :

```
public StopPlaceUpdateTimerTrigger(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
{
    _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: HUGE help.  Trying to migrate a functions app from 2.2 to 3.1 and I used DI for Application Insights in a lot of places.  No mention of this breaking change anywhere in the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: Will this lose correlation information such as `operation_id`? Doing this in an aspnetcore app causes issues with this, I'm unaware if it's the same for functions.

Comment: I found that using this solution made invocationId and cloud_RoleName stop populating, which led to stats not showing up on the function dashboard.  Using Ivan Yang's answer seems to fix this problem.